# Haxe with swf target how do I embed PNG images

Tags: flash, png, haxe

When I run the example here: https://haxe.org/manual/target-flash-resources.html

Then process the output swf using http://www.swftools.org the png file is being embedded with the "DEFINEBITSJPEG2" tag

How do I tell Haxe to embed the png file with the "DEFINEBITSLOSSLESS2" tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem the compiler detects [PNG based on header](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/f8a57dd1676ffcfa9033c204ec99ad831a29f5e8/src/generators/genswf.ml#L219) (so it's best to doublecheck that the file is actually an PNG) and if it does, it [tries to store it as `BitsLossless2`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/f8a57dd1676ffcfa9033c204ec99ad831a29f5e8/src/generators/genswf.ml#L335) (no idea if that tag is any different from `BitsLossless`), but there seems to be an exception for 24bit PNGs exceeding a certain size, which indeed falls back to `BitsJPEG2` (for reasons I don't quite understand). You should be seeing a warning telling you to add an alpha channel. I would suggest trying that.

If all else fails, you can use [resources](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-resources.html) instead, which are [embedded as `BinaryData`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/f8a57dd1676ffcfa9033c204ec99ad831a29f5e8/src/generators/genswf.ml#L257). With `haxe.Resource.getBytes(nameOfTheResource).getData()` you get a `flash.utils.ByteArray` and you can stick that into a `flash.display.Loader` via `loadBytes`.

Comment: My file has a PNG header (the first few bytes are '\x89', 'P', 'N', 'G') and has colorType=TRUECOLOR_ALPHA. I don't see any warnings from Haxe. Will try the resources approach

Comment: Unfortunately, the flash player I have to use for modding (Scaleform for UDK) does not support the DEFINEBINARY tag used for resources. I really need it to use BitsLossless (hopefully BitsLossless2 is ok) as I know that works (Adobe Animate exports this with the same png file and gives a BitsLossless tag it all works fine)

Comment: Looking at the code you [linked](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/f8a57dd1676ffcfa9033c204ec99ad831a29f5e8/src/generators/genswf.ml#L335) that is for an RGB png not RGBA. I think the RGBA is [here](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/f8a57dd1676ffcfa9033c204ec99ad831a29f5e8/src/generators/genswf.ml#L370) but that code path always uses TBitsJPEG3  :( so it looks like Haxe always converts them to JPEG

Comment: Nope, the code you linked is for `@:bitmap(pixels, alphaMask)`, but you're right though, the one I linked is not used for 32bit. Those seem to fall through to `raw`, which just dumps the raw PNG data into a `BitsJpeg2` tag (with PNG header at all). The normal FlashPlayer handles this fine, so I assume Scaleform doesn't?

Comment: The lossless 32 bit format seems to be rather wacky and since the SWF target isn't actively maintained anymore it's unlikely to get support. So in the end the easiest solution is to produce an SWF containing the PNG (via the Flash authoring tool or swftools) and then use it from Haxe via `--swf-lib`.

Comment: Ah ok using the SWFTools works and gives me a DEFINEBITSLOSSLESS2 tag (which outputs a SWF which works with Scaleform!). But how do I access the --swf-lib resource from Haxe?

Comment: You'll need to associate the asset with a class, which you can then instantiate.

Comment: Any idea how to do that? SWFTools png2swf doesn't export the class

Comment: Ok I give up. If anyone wants images to work just convert them to jpg that works fine.

Comment: If I really need png with RGBA in the future I'll make a tool for inserting custom images into an existing adobe animate SWF (which I know works). You can find the format here [kaitai](https://formats.kaitai.io/swf/index.html) and here [swf-file-format-spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf).